# What is the proper way to handle/implement onMouseClick from JavaFX components?

Tags: java, mouseevent, custom-controls, javafx-8

I had a long verbose question here about why my custom control was failing all over the place.
For those who may have experienced something similar I found an EXCELLENT, VERY recent article [here](http://mrt-consulting.com/2014/04/21/custom-controls-and-dialogs-in-javafx/).

It was fantastic, I'm not kidding.

But now I have another problem.
I have several Text shapes on my control that need to respond to mouse clicks (Both single and double) as well as the control itself.

I had before in the JavaFX Scene Builder tool set those controls `On Mouse Clicked` entry in the code section to the same method name, and implemented that name in the controller.
The problem is that this is what was causing things to crash and break and causing me to cry.

For example in the Scene Builder I had all relevant controls `On Mouse Clicked` set to `handleMouse` (Generic method name, I know but it suits my purposes). Then I had in place inside the controller another method that would handle (I thought) the mouse event:

```
@FXML
protected void handleMouse(MouseEvent ME){
    if (ME.getClickCount() > 1) //Do stuff
    else if (/*Other Condition*/) //Do something else
    else if (/*Final Condition*/) //Do something else
}
```

I thought that was correct BUT! Following the guide that I had linked I discovered to my chagrine I am most likely mistaken. When I viewed the controller skeleton for the interface from JavaFX Scene Builder, I discovered it was shelling the event out like so:

```
@FXML
protected void handleMouse(ActionEvent e){
}
```

Now that doesn't seem right. Unless a `MouseEvent` is extended from an `ActionEvent`? Is that the case?

Anyway, I tried to disregard that and do it MY way and it exploded. Surprise surprise, I know now WHY it was exploding.

Even trying to set each `control.onMouseClicked` with a lambda makes it explode:

```
this.texts.stream().foreach((Text txt -> { //texts stores all the controls Text objects for convenient access.
    txt.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent ME) -> {
        //Do stuff here (See above)
    };
});
```

Again, when I killed this code, it worked fine (except for actually doing anything, I mean worked fine in a relative sense, it LOADED without exploding).

So how am I supposed to properly capture the MouseEvent? Is it extended from ActionEvent? Should that even matter? Is this even the REAL reason why it was exploding?

I have more code if needed.

Comment: Your mouse handler method taking a `MouseEvent` looks correct to me. What do you mean by "exploding"? What actually goes wrong?

Comment: To narroy iwt down just a bit more the crash seams to occur at this bit: this.Texts.stream().forEach((Text txt) -> {...});
It never makes it in before breaking down and it throws a pretty generic exception. See this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/92PEmQHQ

Comment: Okay the issue is resolved. It may have been that I was adding the texts to the array BEFORE I was calling the loader, but switching that order seems to have corrected it. Wooh!

Answer (score 0):

I feel I found the problem.
Before my code in the constructor was set like so:

```
this.texts = new ArrayList<>();
this.texts.add(this.shapeName);
this.texts.add(this.shapeNameValue);
this.texts.add(this.shapeScore);
this.texts.add(this.shapeScoreValue);

this.loader = new FXMLLoader(
    this.getClass().getResource("JPlayer.fxml")
);
this.loader.setController(this);
this.loader.setRoot(this);

try { this.loader.load(); }
catch( IOException ex ) { throw new RuntimeException(ex); }
```

Then when I tried to stream the arraylist it caused an exception. I can only conjecture why but adding the elements AFTER seems to have solved the problem. Anyway hopefully this will prove helpful to someone in the future.